# Interpreting '\n' in printf("%s", string)

Tags: c, string, printf

This piece of code is acting a bit strange to my taste. Please, anyone care to explain why? And how to force '\n' to be interpreted as a special char?

```
beco@raposa:~/tmp/user/foo/bar$ ./interpretastring.x "2nd\nstr"
1st
str
2nd\nstr
beco@raposa:~/tmp/user/foo/bar$ cat interpretastring.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s="1st\nstr";

    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Bottom line, the intention is that the 2nd string to be printed in two lines, just like the first. This program is a simplification. The real program has problems reading from a file using `fgets` (not a S.O. argument to `argv` like here), but I think solving here will also solve there.

Comment: Backslash escapes are significant in C *source code*, but they are not significant to `printf` nor `fgets` nor any other C runtime library function.  Command line arguments might get their backslashes converted to something else *by the shell*, but you cannot count on that happening nor can you count on it being consistent with what the C compiler does to string literals.  If you want to translate `\n` to a newline character in your program's input you will have to do that yourself, by hand.

Comment: Thank you. Very pertinent comment. Maybe there is such function already in the vast C library?

Comment: I regret to say that there is no such function.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libcpp/charset.c#l1257 is the core of GCC's implementation of backslash escapes in string literals.  You'll want to read the subroutines too (scroll up) and maybe the calling contexts (scroll down).

Comment: As always, if you downvote, it is important to explain your reasons why you think this question deserves it. Based on that we can edit and improve the question. That is what makes this site great for searching. Thanks.

Comment: Thank @zwol for the link, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all purposes, this just take care of `\n` and no other characters get  special treatment.

This answer here does the job with lower complexity. It does not change "2 chars" into "one single special `\n`". It just changes `<\><n>` to "`<space><newline>`". That's fine. It would be better if there were a `C Standard Library` to interpret special `chars` in a string (as I know it has for `RegExp` for instance).

```
/* change '\\n' into ' \n' */
void changebarn(char *nt)
{
    while(nt!=NULL)
        if((nt=strchr(nt,'\\')))
            if(*++nt=='n')
            {
                *nt='\n';
                *(nt-1)=' ';
            }
}
```

Comment: Of course, now you need to worry about wanting to pass `\` followed by `n` as literals, not newlines. Which means you need to allow backslash to escape itself, so you can pass `"foo\\nbar"` and get `foo\nbar` as a literal output, with backslash and `n`, not a newline.

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger, I thought about that before writing this code. Your comment is very important for those who are reading this answer. As for me, my input doesn't have a literal `"\\n"`. The only special char I need to interpret is just `'\n'`, and a `"\\n"` will be read as `<\>< ><\n>`, no problem. Thanks for point that out, though. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the shell doesn't recognize and convert the "escape sequence". Use a shell software that supports `\n` escape sequence.

Comment: This solution does not address my problem. I don't want third parts to interpret the '\n'. BTW, I also commented in the question about reading a string from a file using `fgets()`.

Comment: So you want code that interprets a the literal 2 characters '\' and 'n' into a single newline character, but you specifically _don't_ want third party code to do that?

Comment: You can't ask me to change my API to solve the problem. The string I get is that, and that is it. I have to deal with it in my own code (or C library). Anyway, it is a simple problem. My question is more about if there is a C library that interprets the string.